# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get password from database:

```
public function getByPassword(){
    $pswd = AdminModel::table('login')->select('password')->get();
}
```

And i get this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()`

My includes are: 
`use App\Models\AdminModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;`

Comment: Can you paste the `AdminModel` code as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
AdminModel::table('login')->select('password')->get();
```

The correct way of fetching data using `eloquent` is:

```
$flights = App\Flight::where('active', 1)
               ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
               ->take(10)
               ->get();
```

`table()` method is used with query builder. Query builder method is:

```
DB::table('login')->select('password')->get();
```

[Reference Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models)

[Reference Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects)